# MYSQL stops working after shrinking an img and writing to a new SD card

Tags: mysql, pi

Get an image of the Pi SD card. Shrink it (using several different methods and utilities) write it to a new SD card. Start up the Pi with the new card. MYSQL doesn't work.

I have tried several utilities from around the web; PiShrink, raspbian-shrink, And one where I did the list of commands myself (tedious for SURE).

Not a code question

I have a Raspberry Pi with a custom set of software that I want to duplicate and use on other Pi's. So to make it faster to copy the image, it is best to shrink it. First, it will fit on different sized cards, and second, it is much smaller, so faster to duplicate.
But after shrinking the image, and writing the image to the new card, MYSQL won't run. Throws this error in my php web application:

SQLSTATE[HY000][2002] No such file or directory

If I try to use phpmyadmin, I get a list of similar errors. I didn't include them as I figure once the issue is corrected, those will go away also.

Everything else on the Pi works just fine as far as I can tell. Any ideas how to fix this?

I have searched for that error and lots of people say to set the host to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost with no clear instructions as to where to set this. None of the examples I have found exist on this thing. Also, if that were the issue, wouldn't it also fail on the original master?
It is not out of drive space as that is one of the responses. The filesystem is expanded to fit the new card so there is plenty of space.

Comment: rhey are talking about the my.cnf file which you find etc/mysql/my.cnf. but ud don't think that is your problem. you changed sop much with the several tools, whatever they are that it dosn't work. Use one tool and see it it still works

Comment: my.cnf doesn't have any "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in it. It does say it imports configuration info from several other places but "127.0.0.1" is already set there instead of "localhost". I changed it per another post to see if it fixed it but to no avail.

Comment: Like i said, i think that you have destroed your filesystem or  least handicapt it. start over look here for a good tutorial https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=32482   To be honest sd cards are cheap and everywhere available, so that a shirking don't sems to be necessary

Comment: Thank you to all who helped! I tried one more method to shrink the image and it worked that time. Apparently the other methods left the filesystem too small. The one I found that worked was pishrink.sh.

Comment: nbk: Thank you for that input, but the issue is that not all are the same actual size. just because it says 16GB don't mean it is actually 16GB. Some are slightly less, some slightly more. You can't put an image that is larger onto a card that is smaller without issues. Shrink the image and it will fit regardless.

Comment: i had that issue at the start of Raspberry Pi, but today you get a 32 or 64 GB card and when the device starts everything is ok